# How do I clean indoor stairs where eggs were broken?

Tags: cleaning, smell, laminate-floor

Several raw eggs (and other assorted garbage) spilled on my townhouse indoor staircase. After carefully cleaning the surfaces, a day later there is still a smell of raw egg (not yet rotten egg smell, but I reckon that's coming). The steps are bamboo laminate, both the treads and risers. (This is 'aftermarket' flooring put in by the previous owner.) There are some visible cracks particularly between the treads and risers (no caulking or filler there), and my concern is that egg goop got into those cracks while wet and is now between the boards, or soaked in under/behind the steps.

There is no access to the bottom/back of the steps.

How do I remove the current 'fresh gross egg' smell, and ensure that there's no egg material rotting under the flooring?

Comment: i would think such a small amount would harden to glue before going rotten and smelling awful. Heat and a fan would help dry it out before it can "turn".

Comment: Soap and water and a whole lot of persistence.